# MVC List Azure Blobs in view without container and path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, blob

I'm putting together a small project management site where a user can upload relevant documents to a project using Azure Blob storage.

I can upload, view the list of blobs and download the blobs, but what I want to do is show the blobs in a list without all the container & path information.

Here's the C#

```
        public ActionResult doclist(int projectid)
    {
        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString", true);
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containername);

        List<CloudBlockBlob> blobs = new List<CloudBlockBlob>();

        //foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, true))
        foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs((containername + "/" + projectid.ToString() + "/").ToString()))
        {
            CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;

            blobs.Add(blob);
        }
        return View(blobs);
    }
```

The view is essentially just a simple

```
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Properties.Length)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", item.Properties.LastModified)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", "Projects", new { filename = item.Name}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
```

I end up with a item.Name value like
"container/project1/document1.jpg"
"container/project1/document2.pdf" etc

All I want to display is 
"document1.jog"
"document2.pdf"

I've tried a simple replace in the HTML, which I've not managed to get it to work.

I've also tried fiddling with the blob data in the C# to change the URI, but don't want that to affect how I download the blob.

Guessing I've missed something really simple here, but this is the first time I've used Blob storage etc.

Am I better off writing this sort of data to a database table and retrieving it from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
    @{
   var itemName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.Uri.LocalPath);
     }
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => itemName)
```

Comment: Hi Naresh, thanks for the quick response. 
this hasn't worked for me. I get the following error

Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: You can move the expression to a variable and use that variable in @Html helper. it resolves that error

Comment: Naresh,

Perfect. Thank you, that works brilliantly. still quite new to manipulating things in HTML